# error when trying to run a code at pycharm and when typing pip at the cmd

Tags: python, node.js, pip

I want to start with web development with python, django, react,  javascript and when I download node.js at the windows PowerShell it showed me that its downloading python again and now when I want to run a code at PyCharm it is showing me this error:

**Error running 'some new sobject': Cannot run program "C:\Users####\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" (in directory ""): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified**

or when I'm typing pip at the cmd it is showing me this error:

**Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users????\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Users????\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.**

I searched for some answers and nothing works should I redownload python?

Comment: your users dir seem to have some special characters in it which can be the cause of this problem: `C:\Users####` and in second error `C:\Users????`, better check how is the dir named and if this is the problem, rename it to `C:\User`, you might have troubles with environment variables and other settings then, but that is a different thing.

Comment: @Ruli my user name is in another language so its just showing this like Unknown Letters

Comment: that might be the cause, try to use another directory for installation as `C:\program files` and see if it works

Comment: so redownload python?

Comment: and one last thing i saw that there was a problem with pip at python 3.9 did they fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Ruli said, it can be due to some special character in the File Name or a Folder, or it can be anything.

My suggestion is to move that whole folder that is default created by PyCharm, and move it somewhere like C:\ , so it is easier to locate the file and run it.

or if you have any other drive like D:\ or E:\ , move it there and try to run the program from the Command Line.

Comment: i already uninstall python i will download it at program files